# Linphone call via DRMF SIP INFO

Tags: swift, linphone

My SWIFT IOS application is: calling with an analog phone via a gateway to a
linphonecore app. And controls some features by means of DTMF.

Is it possible to detect DTMF tones or DTMF in SIP-info with the
linphonecore library ?

Comment: Have you got an answer to this?. please share the answer if it is resolved?